# It is wrong to edit someone else's question if it has been closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, editing

Ever since I have been on the site (which is not very long at all) I have always wondered if it is okay to edit someone else's question after it has been closed if you think that you have the general idea (or can just edit the question to where it makes sense).

The reason why I ask is because I have seen several questions I thought were good, but they were closed as they were deemed either too opinion based or off topic or not very specific. Most of the time, if this were to be allowed, I would be actively editing some of the new users posts when they do not make much sense or need help. I have looked around on this site, but it seems no one has posed the question nor put forth an answer.

What I am looking for is: **Is it okay to edit someone's post when it has been closed?**

Comment: Related: [Should closed questions be edited without fixing the question?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8634/28591)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While it's "OK," you want to do it with caution.

See [What to do when an edit guesses the system being used rather than waiting for the querent to clarify?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6867/what-to-do-when-an-edit-guesses-the-system-being-used-rather-than-waiting-for-th) for a related discussion.  Guessing, even educated guessing, runs the risk of changing the question into something it isn't.

However, while it's closed is the best time to do this - that gives the poster time to correct before answers come in.

In general, if you are inexperienced or unsure, inquire with comments of the OP.  You can submit edits if you're sure and if the OP is engaged.

If the OP isn't doing anything themselves, it's possible it's just a drive-by posting where they are never going to come back so an answer won't help them - this is the Internet after all. That's why we tend to not let people edit in system tags even if "they're sure" - unless the editor is familiar with all editions of D&D and related, they can be wrong, and if the OP isn't invested enough to figure out what game they're playing then we don't really want to spend time on it.

The best time to edit is if:

1. The question is closed
2. The OP is engaged but is having difficulty
3. You have already tried comments
4. You are sure about what's up (and are experienced enough in that area to have expertise that reasonably makes you sure).

Don't be upset if your edit is declined or reverted.

Comment: Also, for recently closed questions, be aware of [the subtle difference between "on hold" and "closed"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10583).